# Set initial scrollbar position with tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, scrollbar, tkinter-canvas

I am trying to create a GUI with tkinter in python with a scrollbar. I am using the grid layout manager because it's the easiest way to organise all the other widgets. Therefore, I have added a scrollbar with the grid layout manager. It works, but my issue is that it is not initially set to the top, but rather somewhere in the middle.

[What it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nx3Vg.png) vs [What it should look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/raGoM.png)

My code looks like this:

```py
from tkinter import *


def button(window, text, command=lambda: None):
    return Button(window, text=text, font=("Ariel", 18), bg="#20bebe", fg="#fff",
    activebackground='#eee', activeforeground='#10aeae', command=command)


root = Tk()

container = Frame(root)
canvas = Canvas(container)
scrollbar = Scrollbar(container, orient="vertical", command=canvas.yview)
buttons_frame = Frame(canvas)

buttons_frame.bind(
    "<Configure>",
    lambda e: canvas.configure(
        scrollregion=canvas.bbox("all")
    )
)

canvas.create_window((0, 0), window=buttons_frame)

canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)

my_list = "a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o".split()

for i in range(len(my_list)):
    button1 = button(buttons_frame, my_list[i])
    button1.config(width=20)

    button2 = button(buttons_frame, my_list[i])

    button1.grid(row=i, column=0, pady=10, padx=10)
    button2.grid(row=i, column=1, pady=10, padx=10)

container.grid(column=1, row=1)
canvas.grid(row=0, column=1)
scrollbar.grid(row=0, column=2, sticky='ns')

root.mainloop()
```

I really can't see what could be causing this, so I'd be thankful if someone could help me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to specify `anchor="nw"` in `canvas.create_window(...)`:

```
canvas.create_window((0, 0), window=buttons_frame, anchor="nw")
```

Otherwise, the `scrollregion` will be set to something like `(-x1, -y1, x2, y2)` and current viewport is `(0, 0, w, h)` where `w, h` are the width and height of canvas.  That is why the scrollbar position is not at the top.